# shape and hollow/solid fill points by 2 factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot points by shape according to `v2` and fill according to `v3`, where fill is solid or hollow. So circles and triangles that are solid or hollow.

I do not want to achieve what I show below: 1 factor with 4 levels. I want 2 factors with 2 levels each.

```
library(ggplot2)
ex <- data.frame(v1=c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"),
                 v2=c("circle", "circle", "triangle", "triangle"),
                 v3=c("filled", "hollow", "filled", "hollow"),
                 v4=c(1, 2, 3, 4))
ex$v5 <- paste0(ex$v2, ex$v3)

ggplot(ex, aes(x=v1, y=v4, shape=factor(v5))) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(19, 1, 17, 2),
                     name = "shapes!",
                     labels = c("circlefilled", "circlehollow",  
                                "trianglefilled", "trianglehollow"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean something like this?

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x=v1, y=v4, shape=factor(v2), fill=factor(v3))) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24),
                     name = "shapes!")+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("black", NA))
```

(for some reason the fill legend seems wrong, I wonder if it's a recent bug).

Alternatively, using alpha

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x=v1, y=v4, shape=factor(v2))) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_point(size=3, aes(alpha=factor(v3)), fill="black") +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 24),
                     name = "shapes!"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(1, 0))
```

but the legend is also somewhat non-ideal (in a different way).

Comment: yes, but i kept getting the fill legend problem as well.

Comment: looks like a bug to me